# How to set Authorization Bearer token header

Tags: go, jwt, http-headers, authorization

I am using JWT tokens for authentication and authorizaton process. I wish to set jwt token in "Authorization: Bearer  ".

```
w.Header().Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+TokenString)
```

I have used the above line to set my token in Authorization header in my response.

I need to use the token to access my other end points.

If I try to access the other end points using this header token. I cant able to do that. I am getting error as no authorization header.

This is my login function

```golang
func (c *Customer) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte("Method mismatch"))
        return
    }
    customer := mappers.Decode(w, r)
    if customer == nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte("Cannot able to parse"))
        return
    }

    err := c.customer.CusotmerLoginService(customer)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte("UNauthorised user or Register first"))
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    token, err := c.customer.GenerateToken(customer)
    if err != nil || token == "" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        w.Write([]byte("Cannot able to generate token"))
        return
    }
    w.Header().Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+TokenString)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
    w.Write([]byte("Logined successfully"))
    return
}
```

The following line is used to get the token from header

authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")

If I use that line, I am getting error as no authorization header.

Comment: Show the __client code__ that is sending the `Authorization` header in _subsequent_ requests. Note also that `Authorization` is a _request-specific_ header and should generally not be used in responses, so `w.Header().Add("Authorization", ...` is bad style.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know how can i set authorization header for all other end points. Can you give me the code for that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Set function.

According to the documentation,
`Add` appends to any existing values associated with key, while `Set` sets the header entries associated with key to the single element value. It replaces any existing values associated with key.

```golang
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+jwtToken)
```